# using $emit multiple times separated by setTimeout in vue not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parent-child, settimeout

I am firing a function in vue that emits a value of true or false to the parent.

This is the child component code:

```
methods: {
   updateProduct(product){
      //this fires properly and returns true
      this.$emit('event_child', true);

     //then I fire a setTimeout function
     setTimeout(() => {
     //do a bunch of tasks and then i attempt another emit
     this.$emit('event_child', false);
     //but the event_child does not update to false in the parent
     }, 3000);
   }
}
```

If I remove the first $emit outside of the setTimeout() (returning true) the parent will show the second $emit (inside setTimeout) correctly (with false value).

In summary, I am having trouble with an $emit and then firing the same $emit (or overriding it?) once I am inside setTimeout.

---

My parent looks like this:

```
<child-component v-on:event_child="eventChild" />
```

and the method:

```
methods: {
            eventChild: function(passed_value) {
                console.log('Event from child component emitted: ', passed_value);
            }
        }
```

For further clarification:

If I do this from the child:

```
this.$emit('event_child', true);
this.$emit('event_child', false);
this.$emit('event_child', true);
```

The console logs correctly: true, false true

If I do the following only:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.$emit('event_child', true);
  this.$emit('event_child', false);
  this.$emit('event_child', true);
}, 3000);
```

The console logs correctly: true, false true

And when I do:

```
this.$emit('event_child', true);
this.$emit('event_child', true);
setTimeout(() => {
  this.$emit('event_child', false);
  this.$emit('event_child', false);
}, 3000);
```

The console only logs: true, true

Comment: It's not reproducible:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/o3s2jeq5/

Comment: How do you call your updateProduct method?

Comment: <form @submit.prevent="updateProduct(product)">

Comment: I have answered the question, I should have mentioned that my component was inside a toggled div using v-if , so when it was toggled the component would be gone from the DOM. I switched to v-show so that the component stays and the results is as expected. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. Thanks to Dan's fiddle I realised that the question I asked actually did not produce any issues. What happened is that I was using the 'passed_value' to toggle a div, and this div had the component inside. When the 'passed_value' was set to false the div including the component were gone, therefore the communication with the component was lost. I changed v-if to v-show in the wrapper div so that the component stayed in the DOM, just hidden.

```
<div v-if="!this.passed_value">
  <child-component v-on:event_child="eventChild" />
</div>
```

to:

```
<div v-show="!this.passed_value">
  <child-component v-on:event_child="eventChild" />
</div>
```

Thanks to everyone for your assistance!